# xpath expression to find url and data

Tags: xpath

i want to get the values of every table   and the href value for every  within the table given below.
Being new to xpath, i am finding it difficult to write xpath expression.
However understanding what an xpath expression does lies somewhat in an easier category.

the expected output

```
http://a.com/   data for a  526735  Z
http://b.com/   data for b  522273  Z
http://c.com/   data for c  513335  Z
```

---

```html
<table class = dataTabe>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><a HREF="http://a.com/" target="_parent">data for a</a></td>
<td class="numericalColumn">526735</td>
<td class="numericalColumn">Z</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a HREF="http://b.com/" target="_parent">data for b</a></td>
<td class="numericalColumn">522273</td>
<td class="numericalColumn">B</td></tr>
<tr>
<td><a HREF="http://c.com" target="_parent">data for c</a></td>
<td class="numericalColumn">513335</td>
<td class="numericalColumn">B</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need two things: an XPath query which locates the wanted nodes and a second which outputs the text as you want it. Since you don't give more information about the languages you're using I'm putting together some pseudocode:

```
foreach node in document.select("//table[class='dataTable']//tr[td/a/@HREF]")
  write node.select("concat(td/a/@HREF,'   ',.)")
```

Comment: the language i am using is java.  
i am using this : //table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr/td/a[@HREF] to fetch the link. but, what it is giving me back, is the value inside a tag, viz. "data for a"

Comment: If you want to select the link itself, do it like this: `//table[@class='dataTable']/tbody/tr/td/a/@HREF` (the `[]` denotes a condition, not a selection)

Comment: works perfectly !!
my secondary problem now, is to find an efficient way to get all repeating child nodes.
That is, i have to get info from 200 child and their 4 child nodes similar to the html file above.
i have created 4 xpath expressions, now i need to evaluate 4 expressions. Putting them in a loop, will require me to evaluate 4*200 times.

Comment: @Himanshu Soni, glad it worked. Please open a new question with an example for your 2nd problem.

Answer (score 0):

This site has a great free tool for building XPath Expressions (XPath Builder):

http://www.bubasoft.net/

Comment: i am using firepath. being integrated with firebug makes it easier to perform xpath debugging

Comment: XPath Builder has nothing to do with debugging in a browser.  It's a standalone program for interactively testing XPath expressions.

Answer (score -1):

Use this XPath: `//tr/td/a/@HREF | //tr//text()`